# How to set the content of textarea as content saved before using useEffect

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-forms

I am trying to make a memo pad using React.
I want to type the text in the text area and save it.
When the page reopens, I want the saved text to remain in the text area.

I am trying to use react-hook-form but I am stuck in useEffect function.
I want to set the textarea in useEffect function by

```
document.getElementById("memoTextarea").value = memo;
```

but this line gives me an error.

Is there anyway to replace the statement?

Below is my code:

```
import { IonPage, IonContent, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonItem, IonItemDivider, IonTextarea, IonButton, IonCard, IonLabel, IonSegment, IonSegmentButton} from '@ionic/react';
import React, { memo, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import './Main.scss';


const Main: React.FC = () => {
    const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (memo: any) =>  console.log(memo);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        let x = document.getElementById("memoTextarea");
        x = memo;
    },[memo]);

    return (

        <IonPage className="MainPage">
            <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>Memo pad</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent fullscreen>
                <IonCard>
                    <form className="memo" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                        <IonItemDivider><IonLabel>Memo</IonLabel></IonItemDivider>          
                        <IonItem>
                            <IonTextarea id="memoTextarea" name="memoTextarea" rows={28} ref={r => register(r)} />
                        </IonItem>
                        <IonButton type="submit" fill="solid">Save</IonButton>
                    </form>
                </IonCard>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>)
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: You are trying to set the value of memoTextArea to ```memo``` that you imported from ```React```.

Comment: @szczocik so what should I do to set the value of memoTextArea to the text that I saved?

Comment: Yeah, it should be some saved string. Also, I don't think you should be manually modifying the DOM. By looking at the react-hook-form it looks like they provide ```defaultValues``` property and ```setValues``` which would be better suited in this case
https://react-hook-form.com/api#setValue

Comment: @szczocik Thank you so much.  I think I will use setValues but do you have any idea how to save string??

Comment: How to save string? You mean on submit? You can save it to local storage or send it to back end and save it in database. There should be a lot of resources to help with that